# -100 Red Flag penalties are sometimes visible

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, flags

Normally, you can't see them. They are only visible to the user itself.

But here are a few cases where you can.

> [image]
>
> [image]

I don't think I should be able to see these on other people's profiles.

Some observations:

- All 4 posts are deleted.
- All 4 posts are accepted.
- All 4 posts are upvoted.

Example:

[image]

---

Mods/Devs, I've left a link to these profiles in the deleted comments. So check the deleted comments.

Comment: Very good point. +1. And become 10k on meta!

Comment: Ahhhhh 10k on meta... Not sure if that's a good thing or a bad thing. :)

Comment: Enjoy your newfound ability to moderate the unicorns :).

Comment: Is a red flag penalty only applied when a post is deleted for spam? (this is the first I've heard of these)

Comment: @Linuxios you're now one step closer to Pundit! ;)

Comment: All 4 posts were upvoted, accepted, and deleted as spam....now I'm sad inside

Comment: FYI It's quite easy to find the user you're talking about. Type a part of the answer in Google. That shows up several scraped results. Some of these contain a question ID. The rest is trivial.

Comment: @RobW Google indexes deleted posts?

Comment: @Mysticial No, but the answer was deleted two years after its appearance ;)

Comment: @RobW Ah... oops. :) I added that screenie in response to MM's comment.

Comment: Oh well, it's not like I found these by chance or with superpowers. Both this and my last meta Q were from Data Explorer anomalies. So anyone else could have done it if they tried hard enough.

Comment: @Mystical because you are high-ranking, how are you able to see the user's reputation penalties due to spam?

Comment: @Mulliganaceous Read the question. It was a bug in the system which has since been fixed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

These edge cases were posts that lasted the 60 day period before being deleted, so there was no "post deletion" event in the history (because there was no rep change from *that* event).  This event is what we use when we hide removed posts in the query...since it didn't exist the exclusion was not happening appropriately.

This affected 68 users in total, they have now been recalced with updated rep code that *does* insert that 0 rep change event, and their profiles will no longer show these spam entries as cache falls out over the next 10 minutes.

Technically, the bug is actually reversed. It's why *didn't* we show the rep change from flags for everyone, all the time...because that penalty is permanent, it doesn't go away with deletion.  However, we are giving users the benefit of the doubt that they *can be better* here as we always do - we feel hiding it from the world (but still visible to the user and moderators) is the correct approach.