# Significantly upvoted posts, not suspended user, yet having only 1 reputation

Tags: support, reputation, reputation-history

Recently digging on the data SE I've found an interesting phenomenon. Namely, [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/121362/abcabc123?tab=topactivity).

They have a question and an answer, both with vote count 4 (if it matters: his question has +5/-1, his answer +4/0).

They are not in a cage.

On these data, I think his reputation should be 1+5*5-2+4*10 = 66.

Despite that, their reputation is only 1.

Their [reputation change history](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/121362/abcabc123?tab=reputation) seems to show the correct values, although their reputation graph shows a *third* value (rep 81, with a small decrease around early January to 79).

Why is it so? What could affect their reputation out of these?

(P.S. I don't know anything about them; I found his page by some data SE digging.)

Comment: Maybe rude/abusive or spam flagged post? That would *earn* -100

Comment: @rene As far I know, negative rep disappears with the deletion of the post. Could you write more about this -100? Anyways, I had a *lot* of similarly flagged posts, but I never got -100 for them. Furthermore, why is the difference with his reputation graph?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216411/show-the-100-for-posting-spam-in-reputation-tab.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

An often-forgotten effect of the "spam" and "rude or abusive" flags are that they impose a -100 penalty on the author of the post if they're actioned (that is to say, if enough spam/abuse flags result in the deletion of a post).

This means that if you post some reasonable questions or answers and then follow them up with, for example, an answer that's nothing but one long stream of vulgarity... You'll end up losing some of the privileges you earned with your previous activity. Unlike reputation gained or lost through normal voting on the post, this penalty remains in effect after the post is deleted (even if it is undeleted and re-deleted).

Moderators are empowered to nullify the penalty in those cases where the flags were in error.

This penalty won't show up on your public reputation history and graphs, but the effects are still visible.

#### See also: [What are the “spam” and “rude or abusive” (offensive) flags, and how do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58032/what-are-the-spam-and-rude-or-abusive-offensive-flags-and-how-do-they-wor)

Comment: Ok, exactly how many of them is needed for this -100?

Comment: See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58032/what-are-the-spam-and-rude-or-abusive-offensive-flags-and-how-do-they-wor

Comment: @peterh TL;DR: 6 from ordinary users, or one from a moderator.

Comment: The penalty not showing is causing more than a bit of [head scratching](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/297479/trying-to-hide-spam-offensive-deletions-on-user-profiles-announces-them) and [wasted effort](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/320948/why-does-this-user-have-only-have-1-rep-but-no-apparent-suspension).