# Reputation and reputation graph out of sync

Tags: bug, stack-overflow, reputation, reputation-graph

I noticed that the top point of the reputation graph is not showing the current reputation as expected. I think this happened after I have reported  some suspicious ratings and I have received some *user removed* messages and a drop on the reputation as well. But there is about 400 difference and I can't see what it is.

I tried to force it recalculate my reputation by visiting the/reputation page but didn't succeed.

Edit: after investigating on reputation history, the only reason that could cause this is the bounty awarded by a deleted user.

Comment: You probably have four posts that were deleted as spam or abusive; the graph doesn't include the -100 penalties from those. See [Reputation on graph doesn't match reputation on account](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/310505/reputation-on-graph-doesnt-match-reputation-on-account)