# Not suspended but still 1 reputation!

Tags: support, reputation

[This user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/810442/coma) has posted a question which has been closed as off-topic. However, they earned 6 reputation from it (thanks to someone who upvoted it). Despite this, they have 1 reputation being shown in their profile (and no they haven't been suspended).

[image: Reputation events]

I figured this out after I saw their reputation graph.

[image: Reputation Graph]

How is this possible?

**Note**: Since now the question has been deleted, everything is back to normal. Also, I am not saying that the user should have had those reputation; I just want to understand the system.

Comment: Caching? The question was at +1/-6 which totals to rep 1 (you cannot go below). Maybe the rep graph hasn't refreshed properly. EDIT: and now the post is gone. So, they would have no rep changes at all.

Comment: @VLAZ but the +1 event happened after 2 downvotes. So, the total couldn't have been 1.

Comment: The user had a spam deletion and because we don't show deleted posts in the reputation history to other users, the penalty is not shown in the calculations. The same effect appears in the opposite direction when a user keeps reputation from an old post after its deleted - phantom reputation from seemingly nowhere.

Comment: This is answered by [Trying to hide spam/offensive deletions on user profiles announces them](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/297479/trying-to-hide-spam-offensive-deletions-on-user-profiles-announces-them): the -100 reputation from spam/offensive deletions is excluded from the graph. (Other types of "private" changes, including downvoting answers and normal deletions, are shown in the graph.)

Comment: @Sonic yes that explains the thing. Thanks.