# Temporarily negative all-time reputation

Tags: bug, reputation, down-votes, reputation-graph

There are quite a few posts on here on meta about *negative reputation*, that received downvotes as they confused time-interval reputation (weekly, monthly, yearly) with all-time reputation.

All time reputation is said to be [always >= 1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2621/why-does-reputation-start-at-1-and-have-a-lower-bound-of-1). I believed that until I ran into the following graph:

[image: reputation graph]

Zooming in will leave us with this:

[image: zoomed reputation graph]

The graph is located at the [reputation tab on the network profile of one such case](https://stackexchange.com/users/2921/sara-chipps?tab=reputation) (in case this will be fixed or removed, [here's an archived version](https://web.archive.org/web/20200914192602/https://stackexchange.com/users/2921/sara-chipps?tab=reputation)).

This graph leaves no room for interpretation: it displays negative all-time reputation over a short amount of time.

What allows for the existence of negative overall-reputation? Is reputation only reset to 1 every once in a while, if you are below that? Was the system *overwhelmed* at that point, for some reason unable of handling the amount of downvotes?

I believe this requires a fix, if it hasn't already been noticed / fixed.

Comment: I guess the down votes came in quicker in that moment in time then the system ever experienced. There are more anomalies with reputation graphs. For example when a user receives a -100 penalty for posting spam / rude posts.

Comment: this is the anomaly I meant: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/297479/trying-to-hide-spam-offensive-deletions-on-user-profiles-announces-them

Comment: I see two deep valleys, -2 and -4