# Why does this user have only have 1 rep but no apparent suspension?

Tags: support, bug, reputation, account-suspension

Update:  The user is now suspended network wide again.

---

Looking at [a user](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/users/384/jeremy?tab=reputation&sort=time) who is suspended on a few sites, but not most<sup>‡</sup>, I see he has a reputation of 1 although the graph says different:

[image: Rep mismatch]

The [API also says that the user is no longer suspended on that site](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/users-by-ids#order=desc&sort=reputation&ids=384&filter=default&site=christianity&run=true).  (He is currently suspended on some other sites and was suspended network-wide until a couple of days ago.)

Adding up the numbers from 2 pages of [the reputation tab](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/users/384/jeremy?tab=reputation&sort=post&page=2) with code like:

```
var reps = $(".rep-cell").map ( (J, node) => {
    return parseInt (node.textContent.trim(), 10);
} ).get ();

ttlRep = reps.reduce ( (total, num) => total + num, 0);
```

yields 61 on the first page and 40 on on the second page for a total of 101.

So,

- Is this user suspended on that site (still) and I just can't see it due to low rep or a bug?
- Did the rep recalc script crash/miss that one user and site combo? (But not the other 174 accounts that the user has.)
- Something else?

---

<sup>‡</sup> Note that all of his network accounts are hidden to the casual user.

Comment: When posts get red flagged and deleted, the rep penalty of -100 kicks in but the graph is never updated to reflect that. It is a known *feature*

Comment: related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/297479/trying-to-hide-spam-offensive-deletions-on-user-profiles-announces-them and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291677/significantly-upvoted-posts-not-suspended-user-despite-he-has-only-1-reputatio/291679#291679

Comment: Thanks, @rene, that is annoying.  I'll attempt to confirm that that is what happened...

Comment: I can confirm it.

Comment: Thank you very much, @Catija.

Comment: Oddly enough, he is suspended network-wide again, this time until XMas 2019.

Comment: @RobertColumbia, yep.  I was researching him because of behavior on my site.  He was a good contributor once.

Comment: He's actually suspended, click on his profile again.