# Why has this user lost all reputation?

Tags: support, reputation

I've stumbled upon [this user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1100921/hamid-vakilian) on Stack Overflow (but I think it could have been on any other site), he lost all his rep in one time, and there's no explanation.

We see this on the graph :

> [image: Interesting part]

But there's nothing here :

> [image: Reputation recap]

What happened to him? Is his account frozen without notice?

Comment: The account isn't suspended. If it was, there'd be a message about it on the profile page. There's something stranger going on here.

Comment: Shot in the dark: Spam/Offensive post deletion generates a 100 rep penalty, and this penalty is not visible in the rep summary to anyone but the user themselves.

Comment: @BillyMailman - post deletion only shows up to the person affected and moderators.

Comment: @ChrisF Well, yeah. But the spam/offensive penalty is separate from the post's deletion; it's a whopping -100 applied separate, and I forget whether it shows up or not.

Comment: @BillyMailman - to be honest I can't remember and I'd have to find someone who had a post flagged as spam on a site where I'm not a moderator to check.

Comment: And now I've looked it up ([here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/183319/226203)). Original comment edited. At any rate, we'll need a mod in here to actually confirm what happened.

Comment: somewhat related: [What happened to this user's rep, badges, and name?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/213000/what-happened-to-this-users-rep-badges-and-name)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A moderator-applied spam flag to the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23126138/19679) imposed a 100-point reputation penalty. Posts deleted via spam flags (either six of them from members of the community, or one spam flag from a moderator) are both deleted and then apply a 100-point penalty to the user involved.

I'll leave commenting on why such a flag was applied to this post to the moderator involved, but I will say there was a coordinated campaign of promotion for a commercial component by this user.